# Store and assert type in a Python class

Tags: python, types, pycharm, warnings, assert

PyCharm CE 2019.2.3 warns me about a class in that I store a `list` of data along with the value data `type`. I have tried to reduce it to the essence:

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, length, data_type):
        assert isinstance(length, int) and length >= 0
        assert isinstance(data_type, type)  # commenting this line out removes the warning
        self._data = [None] * length
        self._data_type = data_type

    def set_field(self, index, value):
        assert isinstance(value, self._data_type)  # commenting this line out removes the warning
        assert isinstance(index, int)
        self._data[index] = value
```

I get a warning on the index:

[image]

> Unexpected type(s):
> (int, type)
>
> Possible types:
> (int, None)
> (slice, Iterable[None])
>
> Inspection Info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotation.

Further comments:

- removing at least one of the two marked assertions removes the warning
- it is rather confusing that the warning appears for the `index` while those asserts refer to the `value`
- adding additional asserts or type-hinting docstrings did not remove the warning for me

**My question:** Am I doing something wrong with this storing and asserting of types? Is there any reason for that warning, and if not, do you see a convenient way to remove it?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of assert.  Asserts should be used when the condition to check is _impossible_ to be false under normal conditions, not when input would cause it to be invalid.   Your type checking is also something you'd be better off using static types for: See https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/ for more info on static typing in python.

Comment: @ChuckAdams I am not surprised that my asserts may not be "appropriate", as I am still quite new to Python. Best practice design patterns usually take the longest in mastering a language. I thought consequent input range checks are an appropriate use case for `assert`s. Anyways, I don't think this inappropriate use of asserts can justify that strange warning behaviour. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is two-fold:

- PyCharm has a bit of a blind spot (at the time of writing) with regards to handling metaclasses correctly with typing. So without additional "hints" it cannot deduce the correct type for `value` currently.
- Because you initialized your list with `None` PyCharm treats it as a list containing Nones.

---

Let's start with the metaclass problem:

You check if `data_type` is a class by checking if it's an instance of `type` (the default metaclass of classes). Then you check if the `value` is an instance of the class. That's fine.

However PyCharm assumes that your `data_type` is a `type` (which is correct) but after the `isinstance(value, self._data_type)` it also assumes that `value` is a `type` (which is incorrect - it should be of type `_data_type`). So just by using `assert isinstance(...)` with `data_type` and `value` PyCharm won't be able to deduce the correct type of `value`!

So this probably qualifies as Bug or missing feature in PyCharm - or in whatever library PyCharm uses to determine the types.

---

The second issue is that by initializing the `_data` with `None` PyCharm will infer the type of `_data` to be `List[None]` (a list containing Nones).

So if PyCharm deduces anything except `Any` (which can be assigned to anything) or `None` (which would be the expected type for the list content) for `value` it will result in a warning.

Even with:

```py
    def set_field(self, index, value):
        assert isinstance(value, int)  # <-- difference
        assert isinstance(index, int)
        self._data[index] = value
```

The warning will come.

---

At this point you have two options:

- Ignore the warning.
- Use full-fledged type-hinting (if the targeted Python version(s) allow for it).

If you want to use type-hinting you could for example use:

```py
from typing import List, Optional, TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

class Data(Generic[T]):

    _data: List[Optional[T]]
    _data_type: Type[T]

    def __init__(self, length: int, data_type: Type[T]):
        self._data = [None] * length
        self._data_type = data_type

    def set_field(self, index: int, value: T):
        if isinstance(value, self._data_type):
            self._data[index] = value
        raise TypeError()
```

Note: I've removed the asserts completely. If arguments don't have the expected type or value a `TypeError` or `ValueError` would be more informative. However in most cases documentation and/or type-hints can adequately replace `assert`s and also `TypeError`s in Python (at least with an IDE or when using mypy).

Comment: PyCharm raises warning on `self._data[index] = value` because `self._data` was initialized with `None` and considered to be `List[None]` by IDE.

Comment: @user2235698 You're right. I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, I can learn a lot from this answer and I feel like I should reconsider my way to ensure types (currently, I hint them in doc strings and `assert` them in addition). I kind of hate that typing is not part of the Python standard, but many possibilities for asserting and hinting are in the room.

Do you think, I should open a ticket towards PyCharm community? I still thin this is a bad way of PyCharm to deduce the types.

Comment: @matheburg I think it would be useful if you file an issue/ticket with PyCharm. It seems like some sort of a problem.